# Add second line to chart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I got a nice looking chart, showing a line for the temperature values. But I can't figure out, how to add a second line for the humidity values that are also included in the JSON output.

I get the data as JSON using `getJSON(url,...)` like that [timestamp, temperature, humidity]:

```
[[1551454476000, 22, 38.900001525878906], [1551454520000, 22, 38.900001525878906], [1551454530000, 22, 38.900001525878906], [1551454547000, 22, 38.900001525878906], ...
```

This is my chart with only one line for temperature:

[image]
This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Fleisch</title>
        <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data.json', function(json) {
            var options =
            {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Kuehlschrank',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type:'datetime',
                    },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperatur'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [],
                    type: 'line',
                    name: "Temperatur"
                    }]
            }

            options.series[0].data = json;

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    }); 

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**I am struggling to add a second line to the same plot for the humidity.** Any help is really appreciated!

---

Update: JSON response

[image]

---

Solution

```
    let humidity = [];
    let temperature = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        temperature.push(json[i][1])
        humidity.push(json[i][2])
    }

    options.series[0] = {
        data: temperature,
        type: 'line',
        name: "Temperature"
    }

    options.series[1] = {
        data: humidity,
        type: 'line',
        name: "Humidity"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add another line by creating a new element of type `object`in your `option.series` array.

So for example :

```
    option.series.push(
      {
         data: // insert your humidity data here
         type: 'line',
         name: "Humidity"
      }
    )
```

You can check an example with  more than 1 line [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/).

EDIT

First you're assigning an array of arrays to your temperature data, when you should only be getting the second element of each array and creating your temperature data with it.

According to your JSON screenshot, this is what you should do to display correctly temperature:

```
let temperature = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
      temperature.push(json[i][1]) // push the second element of each array of information to my temperature arrays
    }
```

Now you need to do the same for your humidity but instead, push the 3rd element(2nd index) from every array of information.

```
let humidity = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
      humidity.push(json[i][2]) // 
    }
```

Now you'll have your temperature and humidity arrays.
Then you can easily assign them to your series like this.

```
   options.series[0] = {
        data: temperature // here you insert the temperature array
        type: 'line',
        name: "Temperature"
    }
   options.series[1] = {
        data: humidity// here you insert the humidity array.
        type: 'line',
        name: "Humidity"
    }
```

Feel free to console.log the temperature and humidity arrays to check what they look like.

Comment: How can I insert the humidity data? I don't know how to use the third element in the JSON array in Javascript

Comment: Just like you did in your example `options.series[0].data = json;`. Data is an `array` of numbers. Can you show me what  your JSON looks like?

Comment: JSON is included in the question. see above

Comment: The JSON is from a response, I can't get the result from it because I don't have access to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/data.json`.

Comment: The result from `http://127.0.0.1:5000/data.json` is like that: `[1551454476000, 22, 38.900001525878906], [1551454520000, 22, 38.900001525878906],...`. It is [timestamp, temperature, humidity]

Comment: Added screenshot from json output

Comment: I've updated my code according to your JSON format, the problem is that you have nested arrays and every nested array contains temperature and humidity, you need to extract them somehow and then assign the extracted values to the 'data' option of your series. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi Sir @VladimirBogomolov, do you mind if I request to have a look at my question [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76776311/multiple-line-on-x-axis-in-a-linear-chart-did-not-show) It is a bit alike to the above but I am a little lost.