# Multiple line on x-axis in a linear chart did not show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js, linechart

I have a single axis line chart. The user would choose the `year` from a dropdown and the `loan_type` from another dropdown. The chart then should load the 12-months record of `annual_payment` and `scheduled_payment`, both as linear lines.

**Dashboard.vue**

```
<div class="card-header bg-white p-2">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <div class="input-group custom-select2">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Loan Type:</span>
                </div>
                <select2 
                    id="selected_loan_type_annual_payment" 
                    name="selected_loan_type_annual_payment" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    v-model="is_inputs.annual_payment.loan_type"
                    @input="selectLoanType($event)" 
                >
                    <option 
                        v-for="(item, index) in types"
                        :key="item.id" 
                        :selected="item.id==is_inputs.annual_payment.loan_type" 
                        :value="item.id">{{ item.text }}
                    </option>
                </select2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <div class="input-group custom-select2">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Year:</span>
                </div>
                <select2 
                    id="selected_year_annual_payment" 
                    name="selected_year_annual_payment" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    v-model="is_inputs.annual_payment.year"
                    @input="selectPaymentYear($event)"
                >
                    <option
                        v-for="(item, index) in years"
                        :key="item.id" 
                        :selected="item.id==is_inputs.annual_payment.year" 
                        :value="item.id">{{ item.text }}
                    </option>
                </select2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div 
      class="col-md-12" 
      v-bind:class="{
        'load_chart': !is_loaded.annual_payment, 
        '': is_loaded.annual_payment
      }"
    >
      <line-chart 
        v-if="is_loaded.annual_payment" 
        :width="100" :height="60" 
        :chartdata="chart_data.annual_payment" 
        :options="chart_options.annual_payment">
      </line-chart>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.
.

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        is_inputs: {
          annual_payment: {
            year: "",
            loan_type: "",
           }
        },
        is_loaded: {
          annual_payment: true,
        },
        chart_options: {
          annual_payment: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: {
              display: true,
              position: 'bottom',
              labels: {boxWidth: 0}
            },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  min: 0,
                  reverse: false,
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        chart_data: {
          annual_payment: {
            labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            datasets: [
             {
              label: [],
              backgroundColor: ['#54478c', '#2c699a', '#048ba8', '#0db39e', '#16db93', '#83e377', '#b9e769', '#efea5a', '#f1c453', '#f35b04', '#bf0603', '#941b0c'],
              data: [],
              borderColor: "#0db39e",
              pointBorderColor: "#bf0603",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#bf0603",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#bf0603",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "#bf0603",
              pointBorderWidth: 6,
              pointHoverRadius: 6,
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
              pointRadius: 3,
              fill: false,
              borderWidth: 2,
              tension: 0.1
             },
             {
              label: [],
              backgroundColor: ['#2c699a', '#54478c', '#0db39e', '#048ba8', '#83e377', '#16db93', '#efea5a','#b9e769', '#f35b04', '#f1c453', '#941b0c','#bf0603'],
              data: [],
              borderColor: "#0db39F",
              pointBorderColor: "#bf0604",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#bf0604",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#bf0604",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "#bf0604",
              pointBorderWidth: 6,
              pointHoverRadius: 6,
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
              pointRadius: 3,
              fill: false,
              borderWidth: 2,
              tension: 0.1
             }
            ]
          }
        },
        selectLoanType(e) {
          this.is_inputs.annual_payment.loan_type = e;
          this.getCreditAnnualPayment();
        },
        selectPaymentYear(e) {
          this.is_inputs.annual_payment.year = e;
          this.getCreditAnnualPayment();
        },
        getCreditAnnualPayment() {
          this.is_loaded.annual_payment = false;
          var loan_type = this.is_inputs.annual_payment.loan_type;
          var year = this.is_inputs.annual_payment.year;
          var data = {'loan_type': loan_type, 'year': year};
          var url = this.routes.annual_payment;
          axios
            .post(url, data)
            .then(response => {
              var json = response.data;
              this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[0].label = year;
              this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[0].data = json;
              this.is_loaded.annual_payment = true;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('err',err);
              this.is_loaded.annual_payment = true;
            });
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**AjaxDataController.php**

```
.
.

public function annual_payment(Request $request) {
    $data = [];
    $selected_loan_type = $request->loan_type;
    $selected_year = $request->year;
    for($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
        $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-n', $selected_year.'-'.($i+1))->format('Y-m');
        $payment_amount = \App\Payment::where('loan_type_id', $selected_loan_type)
            ->where('paid_at', 'like', $dt.'%')->sum('amount');
        $scheduled_amount = \App\Payment::where('loan_type_id', $selected_loan_type)
            ->sum('scheduled_amount');
        $data[$i] = [$payment_amount, $scheduled_amount];
    }  
    return $data;
}

.
.
```

It would be a great help if somebody could point out where did I went wrong and how do I make the correction because at the moment the chart would not load any line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In datasets you have 2 objects. Both objects have `data` property.

You're assigning the array of `[$payment_amount, $scheduled_amount]` to the first object's data property.

I think what you want to do is assign `$payment_amount` to the first object and `$scheduled_amount` to the second object.

Something like this

```
 var json = response.data;
 this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[0].label = year;
 this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[0].data = json[0];
 this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[1].data = json[1];
 this.is_loaded.annual_payment = true;
```

Comment: I have altered my ajax response as well as the controller function. Feel free to give your opinion, Sir.

Comment: @user16780927 does it work now? 

Good `json.payment_amount;` improvement.

Answer (score 0):

**AjaxDataController.php**

```
public function annual_payment(Request $request) {
    $data = [];
    $data1 = [];
    $data2 = [];
    $selected_loan_type = $request->loan_type;
    $selected_year = $request->year;

    for($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
        $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-n', $selected_year.'-'.($i+1))->format('Y-m');
        $payment_amount = \App\Payment::where('loan_type_id', $selected_loan_type)
            ->where('paid_at', 'like', $dt.'%')->sum('amount');
        $scheduled_amount = \App\Payment::where('loan_type_id', $selected_loan_type)
            ->sum('scheduled_amount');
        $data1[$i] = $payment_amount;
        $data2[$i] = $scheduled_amount;
    }  
    $data = [
        'payment_amount' => $data1,
        'monthly_amount' => $data2
    ];
    return $data;
}
```

**Dashboard.vue**

```
.
.
            axios
            .post(url, data)
            .then(response => {
              var json = response.data;
              this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[0].label = year;
              this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[0].data = json.payment_amount;
              this.chart_data.annual_payment.datasets[1].data = json.monthly_amount;
              this.is_loaded.annual_payment = true;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('err',err);
              this.is_loaded.annual_payment = true;
            });
.
.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).